# Binding event to text node

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Here's my HTML. I need to bind a click event to "someText"

```
<div id="container">
    someText <a href="#">A link</a>
</div>
```

"someText" could be any string of text

Comment: If it's clickable, why not put anchor tags on it?

Comment: Wouldn't the click event be on the `div#container` then?

Comment: @Jim Lamb: I can't. It has to be done through javascript unfortunately.

@Jason: That would bind it to the anchor too.

Comment: will the HTML always have the same pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of messing I found a slightly better solution to Patrick's. It can select nodes after the link in this situation, making it more univerally usable. Probably better posting it here :)

```
$('#container')
.contents()
.filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE;
})
.wrap('<span/>')
.parent()
.click(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Use jQuery to wrap the text node with a `<span>`, the place the click on that.

**Try it out:** http://jsfiddle.net/3F4p4/

```
$('#container').contents()  // Get all child nodes (including text nodes)
               .first()     // Grab the first one
               .wrap('<span/>')    // Wrap it with a span
               .parent()           // Traverse up to the span
               .click(function() { alert('hi'); });​​  // add the click to the span
```

The `.contents()` method returns all child nodes, including text nodes. So you grab the first child, wrap it, traverse to its parent (which is now the span), and add the click.

- http://api.jquery.com/contents/
- http://api.jquery.com/wrap/
- http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Comment: Can you explain why it's needed to wrap with a <span>

Answer (score 1):

Hacky way **whithout any changing of html** markup:

1. Add `contenteditable` attribute to container.
2. On click look at the selected node via `document.getSelection()` and check it.
3. If selected text node is the very node, do what you want.
4. Reset selection.

http://jsfiddle.net/quqtk8r6/2/

```
var el = document.getElementById("container")
el.setAttribute("contenteditable", "true")
el.style.cursor = "pointer"
el.style.outline = "none"
el.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var selection = document.getSelection(),
      node = selection.baseNode

  selection.removeAllRanges()
  if (node.nodeType == 3 && node.parentNode == el) {
    alert("someText are clicked")
  }
})
el.addEventListener("keydown", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  return false
})
```

PS: It's more food for thought rather than real recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Either wrap it in `<a>` or `<div>` tags and assign the click event to that element.

```
  <a href="#" id="sometext">someText</a>

  $("#sometext").click(function() {
       do stuff here...
  });
```